# Add hexdecimal values which are dictionary values and not convert them to decimal values

Tags: python

I have a dictionary who's values are in hexadecimal form. I need to add the values and the result should be in hexadecimal form. Please provide solution for adding hex values and result should be hex.

Using `sum1 = sum(dict.values)` provides only sum for values which are in int form. It doesn't work for hex.

```py
dict = {'key1': '1C','key2': '14','key3': '4D'}

print("Value : %s" %  dict.values())
```

`Value : dict_values(['1C', '14', '4D'])`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly `sum` the hex values since they are strings. You need to convert them to `int` and then convert the answer back to hex. You can do that as follows:

```
hex(sum(map(lambda v: int(v, base=16), d.values())))
```

(`d` is the name of the dict. Please avoid using `dict` as the variable name, since it is also the class name)